# Mysql : How to check uniqueness of pair

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   CREATE TABLE nodes (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        feat1 CHAR(1), -- e.g., age
        feat2 CHAR(1)  -- e.g., school attended or company
   );

   CREATE TABLE edges (
        a INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
        b INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
   );

   CREATE INDEX a_idx ON edges (a);
   CREATE INDEX b_idx ON edges (b);
```

If we want to represent an undirected graph, we need to add a CHECK constraint on the uniqueness of the pair.

Since the SQL standard does not allow a subquery in the CHECK constraint,How can i check uniqueness of the pair?

Comment: Just clarifying - the goal here is preventing e.g. both (1, 2) _and_ (2, 1) from appearing in the table - is that right?

Comment: yes that is right. Also there should not be any self loops.

Answer (score 7):

You could rig up a trigger that fails upon seeing either `(A,B)` or `(B,A)` :

Here is the Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER edges_bi BEFORE INSERT
ON edges FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE found_count,dummy,diff,SomethingsWrong INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE errmsg VARCHAR(128);
    SET diff = new.a - new.b;
    IF diff = 0 THEN
        SET errmsg = CONCAT('[',new.a,',',new.b,'] is Vertex, Not Edge');
        SET SomethingsWrong = 1;
    END IF;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_count FROM edges
    WHERE (a=NEW.a AND b=NEW.b) OR (a=NEW.b AND b=NEW.a);
    IF found_count = 1 THEN
        SET errmsg = CONCAT('[',new.a,',',new.b,'] Already Exists');
        SET SomethingsWrong = 1;
    END IF;
    IF SomethingsWrong = 1 THEN
        SELECT errmsg INTO dummy FROM edges WHERE 1=1;
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a sample table:

```
DROP DATABASE if exists saurabh;
CREATE DATABASE saurabh;
USE saurabh
CREATE TABLE edges
(
   a INTEGER NOT NULL,
   b INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (a,b),
   UNIQUE KEY (b,a)
);
```

Notice that I have a PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE KEY with the columns of the PRIMARY KEY reversed

Let's create the table:

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE if exists saurabh;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE saurabh;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE saurabh
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE edges
    -> (
    ->    a INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ->    b INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ->    PRIMARY KEY (a,b),
    ->    UNIQUE KEY (b,a)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's create the Trigger:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER edges_bi BEFORE INSERT
    -> ON edges FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE found_count,dummy,diff,SomethingsWrong INT DEFAULT 0;
    ->     DECLARE errmsg VARCHAR(128);
    ->     SET diff = new.a - new.b;
    ->     IF diff = 0 THEN
    ->         SET errmsg = CONCAT('[',new.a,',',new.b,'] is Vertex, Not Edge');
    ->         SET SomethingsWrong = 1;
    ->     END IF;
    ->     SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_count FROM edges
    ->     WHERE (a=NEW.a AND b=NEW.b) OR (a=NEW.b AND b=NEW.a);
    ->     IF found_count = 1 THEN
    ->         SET errmsg = CONCAT('[',new.a,',',new.b,'] Already Exists');
    ->         SET SomethingsWrong = 1;
    ->     END IF;
    ->     IF SomethingsWrong = 1 THEN
    ->         SELECT errmsg INTO dummy FROM edges WHERE 1=1;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END; $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (5,3);
INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (3,5);
INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (5,5);
SELECT * FROM edges;
```

Let's try loading these into the `edges` table:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (5,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (3,3);
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '[3,3] is Vertex, Not Edge' for column 'dummy' at row 1
mysql> INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (3,5);
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '[3,5] Already Exists' for column 'dummy' at row 1
mysql> INSERT INTO edges (a,b) VALUES (5,5);
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '[5,5] is Vertex, Not Edge' for column 'dummy' at row 1
mysql> SELECT * FROM edges;
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 5 | 3 |
+---+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that blocking A=B conditions prevents any self-loops

## CAVEAT

This trigger does not work if

- you start with an empty table
- enter `(3,3)` as the first row

because the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger does not fire on an empty table.

Once you enter a valid row with `A` <> `B` then all checks are performed properly.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support CHECK constraints.

You can create a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to check this situation, and throw an error if needed.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE edges(
  a INT(11) NOT NULL,
  b INT(11) NOT NULL
);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON edges
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @cnt = NULL;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM edges
    WHERE a = new.a AND b = new.b OR a = new.b AND b = new.a;

  IF @cnt > 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: uniqueness of pair';
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Also, create similar BEFORE UPDATE trigger to avoid NEW wrong values on updating, or just use a stored procedure because the code is the same.

Answer (score 2):

`CHECK` is not supported on `CREATE TABLE` by MySQL, as the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) dictates

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines

In fact there is an [open bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464) on that issue since 2004 (!).

The approach I would take is to create a stored procedure trigger on insert and on update that deliberate fails if the pair exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think an answer may depend on how you are populating the `edges` table, which is not clear from your question. If it is being populated from the `nodes` table, then you may be able to build a VIEW based on a SELECT query that excludes the mirrored pairs (i.e. 1,2 and 2,1). This might also solve the cascade and delete requirement.